NSAttributedString link color not changing in swift
Im working on an IOS app using swift and facing an issue with NSAttributedString where im trying to apply a hyperlink to a substring of a text. The hyperlink is functional but the link color remains white instead of changing to the desired blue color specified in the attributes. It seems like my attribute settings are being overridden. Here is a code snippet:
let subString = String(format: GMLocalizedString("gcm_training_status_vo2_max_description_4"), GMLocalizedString("activities_cooper_institute"))
let footerString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: subString, attributes: textAttributes.secondaryDescription)
if let substringRange = subString.range(of: GMLocalizedString("activities_cooper_institute")) {
    let nsRange = NSRange(substringRange, in: subString)

    let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: GCMTheme.uiColor.textAction,
        .link: Constants.cooperInstituteHyperlink
    ]
    footerString.addAttributes(linkAttributes, range: nsRange)
}
vo2MaxParagraph.append(footerString)

I have tried setting .foregroundColor in linkAttributes to the theme's textAction color, but the color remains white. I know that the color is correct because if i remove the attribute related to the link the text changes color, just has no functionality. How can I ensure that the color of the hyperlink changes as intended? Is there another place in my code that could be overriding these settings?

How do you show them? For instance, if it's a UITextView, it has linkTextAttributes.

I guess im not sure. Im fairly new to UIKit. Is there a way for me to check within the file?

Some further digging in the file and i discovered a func that adds text to a stack view. In the func it utilized textView. Changed the default foreground color. Thanks for the help!
